# The Path to the Result

Tags: code-golf, string, arithmetic

**Input:**

A grid of varying size only containing numbers in the range `00-99`, the following four characters: `^`; `>`; `v`; `<`, and spaces to fill (and new-lines of course).

**Output:**

The result of the sum (integer) when you follow the path.

**How does this work?**

You start at the arrow with the highest number, and follow the path the arrows point to.
For each of the four arrows we'll do a different arithmetic calculation:

- `>` = Addition (+);
- `<` = Subtraction (−);
- `^` = Multiplication (* or × or ·);
- `v` = Real / Calculator Division (/ or ÷);

(NOTE: The symbols between parenthesis are just added as clarification. If your programming language uses a completely different symbol for the arithmetic operation than the examples, then that is of course completely acceptable.)

**Challenge rules:**

- You can choose the input (to some extent). A string-array would be most logical I think, but a symbol/newline-separated single string is also fine. (Full functions as input that are simply executed in the actual code snippet aren't allowed!)
- Trailing spaces for the input are optional.
- Numbers `0-9` will have a leading `0` so all numbers plus arrow are of an equal three-character length.
  The number & arrow will always have the following format: `DDA` (`D` being a digit; `A` being one of the four arrows).
- You use the current value with the previous arithmetic operation (the example below explains this better).
- The final arithmetic operation can be ignored because of the rule above.
- It is possible to have *DDA*'s in the input-grid that aren't being used in the path to the resulting sum.
- There won't be any test-cases for arrows that form a loop.
- There won't be any test-cases for dividing by 0.
- There won't be any test-cases where dividing creates a decimal sum-result. You only have to worry about integers.
- ***EDIT: Since there weren't any answer yet, I decided to change the grids slightly to perhaps make it easier. I know this is usually not recommended to do with challenges, but since no answers were given yet, I think this will make it slightly easier, giving more (/any) answers:***
  <s>The spaces between de *DDA*'s are random. There could even be no spaces in between at all.</s> All *DDA*'s and spaces are grouped per three. Also, it is possible to have no spaces between *DDA*'s at all.

**Example:**

*Input:*

```
94>      66v
   05v   08<
         43>
   03>   00^
```

*Path it follows:*

```
Path it follows   |   Current sum value
________________________________________
94>               |   94  (highest value)
66v               |   160 (+)
08<               |   20  (/)
05v               |   15  (-)
03>               |   5   (/)
00^               |   5   (+)
43>               |   215 (*)
                          '>' after 43 is ignored because it's the last number
```

*Output:* 215

**General Rules:**

- This is [code-golf](/questions/tagged/code-golf), so shortest answer in bytes wins.
  Don't let code-golf languages discourage you from posting answers with non-codegolfing languages. Try to come up with an as short as possible answer for 'any' programming language.
- [Standard rules apply](http://meta.codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/2419/default-for-code-golf-program-function-or-snippet/2422#2422) for your answer, so you are allowed to use STDIN/STDOUT, functions/method with the proper parameters, full programs. Your call.
- [Default Loopholes](http://meta.codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/1061/loopholes-that-are-forbidden-by-default) are forbidden.
- If possible, please add a link with a test for your code.
- Also, please add an explanation if necessary.

**Test cases:**

```
94>      66v           ->     215
   05v   08<
         43>
   03>   00^


77>   80v55^02<        ->     -19
      20>   14^


22>11>15>80>14v        ->     -16
18^17>      10v
00^   90v43^02v
07^11<15<22v01<


99>98>97>96>95>94v     ->     102
93>92>   91v   03<
```

Comment: I keep finding -12 for the third test case...

Comment: @PaulPicard Ah, I'm so sorry, there was a mistake in the grid.. `07<` has been changed to `07^` to fix this.

Comment: Could somebody please tell me what I'm misunderstanding with the second one? As I see it, it is: `77+80/20+14*2-55=-11.3` without order of operations.

Comment: @Dopapp You start at the highest value, so it's 80/20+14*2-55=-19

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## Python 2, <s>409</s> <s>390</s> 377 bytes

```py
def f(p):
 p=map(lambda s:map(lambda d:d==3*(' ',)and(0,-1)or(int(d[0]+d[1]),'><^v'.index(d[2])),zip(s[::3],s[1::3],s[2::3])),p);x,y=max([(x,y)for x in range(len(p[0]))for y in range(len(p))],key=lambda(x,y):p[y][x][0]);r=o=0
 try:
  while 1:
   1/(y*x>=0);d=p[y][x]
   if-1<d[1]:r=eval('r%sd[0]'%'+-*/'[o]);o=d[1];a=(-(o==1),1)[o<1];b=(-(o==2),1)[o>2]
   x+=a;y+=b
 except:print r
```

The second and third indent levels are a raw tab and a raw tab plus a space, respectively. Markdown mangles the raw tabs, so they've been replaced by two spaces.

Ungolfed:

```py
def follow(path):
  # Split path's strs into DDAs ((0, -1) for blank, else (int, int))
  path = map(
    lambda s: map(
      lambda dda: (0, -1) if dda == (' ', ' ', ' ') else (int(dda[0] + dda[1]), '><^v'.index(dda[2])),
      zip(s[::3], s[1::3], s[2::3])
    ),
    path
  )

  # Find highest DDA
  x, y = max([(x, y) for x in range(len(path[0])) for y in range(len(path))], key=lambda (x, y): path[y][x][0])

  result = 0
  op = 0  # addition
  try:
    # Keep following the path until we get an IndexError
    while True:
      if y < 0 or x < 0: raise IndexError

      dda = path[y][x]
      if dda[1] != -1:
        # It's not empty - do the operation & change direction
        const = dda[0]

        result = eval('result %s const' % '+-*/'[op])

        op = dda[1]

        dx = 1 if op == 0 else -1 if op == 1 else 0
        dy = 1 if op == 3 else -1 if op == 2 else 0

      # Move to the next thing
      x += dx
      y += dy
  except IndexError:
    # We've exited the path - return
    print result
```

[Ideone it! (all test cases)](http://ideone.com/IdpEEt)

Answer (score 0):

### Python 2, 449 bytes

```
i=input();p,d,a,o,l=[-1,0],">",0,"+",0
for y in range(len(i)):
 for x in range(len(i[0])):
  if i[y][x]in"><^v":
   v=int(i[y][x-2]+i[y][x-1])
   if v>l:l=v;p=[x-2,y]
while 1:
 if d==">":p[0]+=1
 if d=="<":p[0]-=1
 if d=="^":p[1]-=1
 if d=="v":p[1]+=1
 try:
  c=i[p[1]][p[0]]
  if c in"><^v":
   d=c
   if p[0]<0 or p[1]<0:1/0
   a=eval(str(a)+o+str(int(i[p[1]][p[0]-2]+i[p[1]][p[0]-1])));o={">":"+","<":"-","^":"*","v":"/"}[c]
 except:print a;break
```

This takes an array of strings as input

Ungolfed:

```
pointer = [-1,0]
dir = ">"
output=0
operation="+"

largest = 0
for y in range(len(input)):
    for x in range(len(input[0])):
        if input[y][x] in "><^v":
            value = int(input[y][x-2]+input[y][x-1])
            if value > largest: largest = value; pointer = [x-2, y]

while 1:
    if dir==">":pointer[0]+=1
    if dir=="<":pointer[0]-=1
    if dir=="^":pointer[1]-=1
    if dir=="v":pointer[1]+=1
    try:
        current = input[pointer[1]][pointer[0]]
        if current in "><^v":
            dir = current
            value = int(input[pointer[1]][pointer[0]-2]+input[pointer[1]][pointer[0]-1])
            
            if pointer[0]<0 or pointer[1]<0:1/0
            output=eval(str(output)+operation+str(value))
            
            if current==">":operation="+"
            if current=="<":operation="-"
            if current=="^":operation="*"
            if current=="v":operation="/"
    
    except:
        print output;break
```